# Merge k sorted arrays, with different lengths

Tags: arrays, sorting, merge

n is a power of 2. Given logn-1 sorted arrays length 1,2,4,8,...,n/2 each one, describe deterministic algorithm to merge them into one sorted array. 
I thought maybe to keep pointer to each one of the sorted array first element, insert all first items into binary heap, and delete min. But the fact that the lengths are different makes me think maybe this solution isn’t the best one.

What is the most efficient way to solve this?

Comment: Thats a interesting question but if i remember answer correctly from my days. You need to merge them one by one as merge array of size 1 with array of size 2 and get a array of size 3. Merge array of size 3 with the array of size 4..and so on..this way you are still comparing only 2 elements every time and dont need that min heap.

Answer (score 0):

Merge smallest runs. In this case merge runs of size {1,2} to create a run of size 3. Merge runs of size {3,4} to create a run of size 7. Merge runs of size {7,8} to create run of size 15. ... and so on.

This is the situation when doing a bottom up merge sort on linked lists, which uses a small array of "lists" (pointers or references to nodes), where array[i] is a list of size 2^i {1,2,4,8,...}. After merging all nodes from the source list into the array, the array is then merged into a single list, starting from array[0].

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists